# Comparing 2 different columns in different spreadsheets using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have 2 spreadsheet files in Excel. The task I am trying to complete entails that if the values in file 1/spreadsheet 1 appear in file2/spreadsheet 2, I need to remove them from the column of values in file 1. I know how to do this in excel already but am new to Python and am still learning syntax and methods on how to accomplish tasks like this. For example...

```
Age file 1:        Age file 2:
   10                 12
   25                 19
   33                 55
   19                 37
   55                 77
```

So my question is if the age 19 has a duplicate in the other column/file how would I drop it from the column using a pandas function? I have read a few things about the compare function as well as dropping duplicates but between 2 different excel files I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by turning both files into dataframes and then running standard comparisons. There's no example code or desire output but the below format should work for your needs.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)

df1 = df1[~df1'Age file'].isin(df2['Age file'])
```

I'm including a link in case you have more questions  like this.
[https://www.statology.org/pandas-not-in/#:~:text=How%20to%20Use%20%E2%80%9CNOT%20IN%E2%80%9D%20Filter%20in%20Pandas,show%20how%20to%20use%20this%20syntax%20in%20practice](https://www.statology.org/pandas-not-in/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Use%20%E2%80%9CNOT%20IN%E2%80%9D%20Filter%20in%20Pandas,show%20how%20to%20use%20this%20syntax%20in%20practice).